# Removing duplicate rows in a complex MySQL Query - not sure if I'm doing this wrong, or it's a MySQL bug

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a reasonably complex MySQL query being run on another developer's database. I am trying to copy over his data to our new database structure, so I'm running this query to get a load of the data over to copy. The main table has around 45,000 rows.

As you can see from the query below, there's a lot of fields from several different tables. My problem is that the field `Ref.refno` (as `ref_id`) is being pulled through, in some cases, two or three times. This is because in the table `LandlordOnlineRef` (`LLRef`) there are sometimes multiple rows with this same reference number - in this case, because the row *should* have been edited, but instead was duplicated...

**Here's what I've tried doing:** -

1. `SELECT DISTINCT(Ref.refno) [...]` - this makes no difference to the output at all, although I would've assumed it would stop selecting duplicate `refno` IDs
2. **Is this a MySQL bug, or me?** - I also tried adding `GROUP BY ref_id` to the end of my query. The query normally takes a few milliseconds to run, but when I add `GROUP BY` to the end, it seems to run infinitely - I waited several minutes but nothing was happening. I thought it might be struggling because I'm using `LIMIT 1000`, so I also tried `LIMIT 10` but still get the same effect.

Here's the problem query - thanks!

```
SELECT 

    -- progress
    Ref.refno                   AS ref_id,
    Ref.tenantid                AS tenant_id,
    Ref.productid               AS product_id,
    Ref.guarantorid             AS guarantor_id,
    Ref.agentid                 AS agent_id,
    Ref.companyid               AS company_id,
    Ref.status                  AS status,
    Ref.startdate               AS ref_start_date,
    Ref.enddate                 AS ref_end_date,

    -- ReferenceDetails
    RefDetails.creditscore      AS credit_score,

    -- LandlordOnlineRef
    LLRef.propaddress           AS prev_ll_address,
    LLRef.rent                  AS prev_ll_rent,
    LLRef.startdate             AS prev_ll_start_date,
    LLRef.enddate               AS prev_ll_end_date,
    LLRef.arrears               AS prev_ll_arrears,
    LLRef.arrearsreason         AS prev_ll_arrears_reason,
    LLRef.propertycondition     AS prev_ll_property_condition,
    LLRef.conditionreason       AS prev_ll_condition_reason,
    LLRef.consideragain         AS prev_ll_consider_again,
    LLRef.completedby           AS prev_ll_completed_by,
    LLRef.contactno             AS prev_ll_contact_no,
    LLRef.landlordagent         AS prev_ll_or_agent,

    -- EmpDetails
    EmpRef.cempname             AS emp_name,
    EmpRef.cempadd1             AS emp_address_1,
    EmpRef.cempadd2             AS emp_address_2,
    EmpRef.cemptown             AS emp_address_town,
    EmpRef.cempcounty           AS emp_address_county,
    EmpRef.cemppostcode         AS emp_address_postcode,
    EmpRef.ctelephone           AS emp_telephone,
    EmpRef.cemail               AS emp_email,
    EmpRef.ccontact             AS emp_contact,
    EmpRef.cgross               AS emp_income,
    EmpRef.cyears               AS emp_years,
    EmpRef.cmonths              AS emp_months,
    EmpRef.cposition            AS emp_position,

    -- EmpLlodReference
    ELRef.lod_ref_status        AS prev_ll_status,
    ELRef.lod_ref_email         AS prev_ll_email,
    ELRef.lod_ref_tele          AS prev_ll_telephone,
    ELRef.emp_ref_status        AS emp_status,
    ELRef.emp_ref_tele          AS emp_telephone,
    ELRef.emp_ref_email         AS emp_email

FROM ReferenceDetails AS RefDetails

LEFT JOIN progress          AS Ref      ON Ref.refno
LEFT JOIN LandlordOnlineRef AS LLRef    ON LLRef.refno = Ref.refno
LEFT JOIN EmpLlodReference  AS ELRef    ON ELRef.refno = Ref.refno
LEFT JOIN EmpDetails        AS EmpRef   ON EmpRef.tenantid = Ref.tenantid

-- For testing purposes to speed things up, limit it to 1000 rows
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Where there are multiple rows with the same refno, how do you intend to resolve the different values on each row? Does ReferenceDetails include a date field that can be used to determine when the record was last edited?

Comment: @MarkBannister good point - this is a tricky one as I want the most recent, but ReferenceDetails doesn't have a date associated. Also we can't guess at it from the IDs auto-incrementing, as the developer of this previously database created *random* IDs for each row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LEFT JOIN progress          AS Ref      ON Ref.refno
```

is going to basically turn that into a cartesian join. You're not doing an explicit comparison, you're saying "join all records where there's a non-null value".

Shouldn't it be

```
LEFT JOIN progress          AS Ref      ON Ref.refno = RefDetails.something
```

?

Comment: Woah... didn't spot that! Guess your mind gets a bit boggled writing queries like this all day. Set it to `LEFT JOIN progress AS Ref ON Ref.refno = RefDetails.refno`. Whilst the output's the same, this seems to have fixed my `GROUP BY` problem...

Answer (score 1):

1. Put all of the selected columns into `DISTINCT`, separated by `,`. If you want to keep the renaming, wrap another `SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM (YOUR_SELECT)` around.
2. Are there indexes on the columns in the `GROUP BY` clause? `LIMIT` is applied after `GROUP BY`. So limiting does not affect the query runtime.

Comment: 1. I have done it so that it is like this: `SELECT DISTINCT Ref.refno AS ref_id, Ref.tenantid AS tenant_id [...]` as this was the only way I could find which didn't generate a syntax error (although I'm not sure this is correct as it didn't make any difference...?)

Comment: 2. Yes, there are indexes on the columns.

Comment: Try the `SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM ...` around your query.

Answer (score 0):

General rule is to never group by more columns then you have to.  Use a subquery with a group by on the table thats returning duplicate rows to get rid of them.

Change:

```
LEFT JOIN LandlordOnlineRef AS LLRef    ON LLRef.refno = Ref.refno
```

to:

```
Left Join (select refno
, othercolumns you need 
from LandlordOnlineRef 
group by refno,othercolumn) as LLRef
```

Not sure on which columns you'll want to include here, but at any table level, you can change that table to a subquery to eliminate duplicate rows before the join. As MarkBannister says, you'll need some logic to identify a unique refno within LLRef .   You can also use a date column for 'most recent' or any other logic you can think of to get back a unique LLRef and the info related to that record.

ugh, auto spell check is changing refno to refine.  ha